# Why would 00 in data break UTF-16 encode / OpenSSL?

Tags: php, authentication, openssl, utf-16

I'm working on a PHP login that takes an ID and logs them in elsewhere after the user is already authenticated. It works for every single ID except three of them, and they all have something in common: They all start with two zeros (e.g.: 0012).

I'm wondering if a double zero holds a special place in the encoding, like a delimiter? Or something to do with OpenSSL? It only breaks on those three. Doesn't matter if I treat the data as a string or an integer, it breaks both ways. Any ideas?

Code (modified slightly):

```
            $fp = fopen("/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/myrsakey.pem", "r");
            $priv_key = fread($fp, 8192) or die("File not found."); 
            fclose($fp);

            $pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);

            $data = '0012'; // THIS DOESN'T WORK
            $data = '0123'; // THIS DOES WORK
            $data = '1234'; // THIS ALSO WORKS

            $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "UTF-16LE");

            openssl_sign($data, $signature, $pkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1); 
            openssl_free_key($pkeyid);
```

Comment: Side-Note: You can simply load your private key by using `$priv_key = openssl_pkey_get_private("file:///OpenSSL-Win64/bin/myrsakey.pem");`

Comment: Are the double-zeros at the beginning the only thing that distinguishes those IDs from the rest? Or are those generally the only ones starting with a zero?

Comment: There's a bunch of other ID's as well, they can be any combination of 4 numbers (eg: 1234, 2454). It only breaks on the ID's that start with 00. All the other data is the same.

Comment: Does `openssl_verify` using the public key on `$data` starting with 00 immediately after creating the signature succeed?

Comment: Yes, it returns true no matter the case.

Comment: In that case: Are you sure the problem is on your end? Everything seems fine so far.

Comment: I'm really starting to wonder if it is on my end; the other party says that they have not heard of any issue like this before. I'd assume they also have other login ID's on other systems starting with 00, but maybe not. Maybe I shouldn't assume! thanks for all the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would 00 in data break UTF-16 encode / OpenSSL?

The problem is *not* with OpenSSL. OpenSSL just works with data - it does not care about encodings. It might be related to `openssl_sign`. But its hard to tell at the moment.

Your problem is likely related to `mb_convert_encoding`. However, you never stated what the actual problem was.

How does it not work? Does it not work when verifying the signature on a Linux system? Did you check for the presence (or absence) of a Byte Order Mark (BOM)? That's a real problem, especially when working with Java.

Comment: It should sign in the member after a redirect to a URL; it does for any ID not starting with a double zero. I also have assumed it's related to `mb_convert_encoding`. After it leaves my end though it's up to the other party (which I do not have access to) to accept that data so I'm pretty limited in my testing other than just continue sending requests. I just want to make sure everything on my end it up to snuff or if anyone had something similar they had seen. I have not tried to test it on a Linus system yet -- and no Java involved. Just PHP.